# Creating a feed of events ordered by Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to create a feed on the Users page where it will display if the user has recently liked something, created an item, commented on a post etc. How will I do that? I was thinking of making a list of object of the different information I get from my database then order by date but I cannot get the code to order correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, what I ended up doing was something along these lines:

```
public class UserFeed
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Reference_Id { get; set; }
    public int Comic_Id { get; set; }
    public int Chapter_Id { get; set; }
    public int Page_Id { get; set; }
    public int User_Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public decimal Rating { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

 List<UserFeed> userFeed = new List<UserFeed>();
 userFeed.AddRange(user.SelectMany(i => i.UserFavorites).Select(i => new UserFeed { Type = "UserFavorite", Reference_Id = i.UserFavorite_Id, Comic_Id = i.Comic_Id, Title = i.Comic.Title, Image = i.Comic.ComicImage, Date = i.DateFavorited }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Date).Take(6));
 userFeed.AddRange(Comics.SelectMany(i => i.ComicReviews).Select(i => new UserFeed { Type = "ComicReview", Reference_Id = i.ComicReview_Id, Comic_Id = i.Comic_Id, Title = i.Comic.Title, Text = i.Text, Rating = i.ComicRating.Rating, Image = i.Comic.ComicImage, Date = i.DatePublished }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Date).Take(6));
 userFeed.AddRange(Comics.SelectMany(i => i.Chapters).Select(i => new UserFeed { Type = "Chapter", Reference_Id = i.Chapter_Id, Comic_Id = i.Comic_Id, Title = i.Title, Image = i.Comic.ComicImage, Date = i.DatePublished }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Date).Take(6));
 userFeed.AddRange(Comics.SelectMany(i => i.Chapters.SelectMany(j => j.Pages)).Select(i => new UserFeed { Type = "Page", Reference_Id = i.Page_Id, Chapter_Id = i.Chapter_Id, Title = i.Title, Image = i.PageImage, Date = i.DatePublished }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Date).Take(6));
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a `userFeed = userFeed.OrderByDescending(feed => feed.Date)` at the end to get the whole list sorted, unless you want a block of Favorites followed by a block of Reviews, etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var feed = db.Likes
    .Where(like => like.UserID == currentUserID)
    .Where(like => like.CreatedAt > createdSince)
    .OrderByDescending(like => like.CreatedAt)
    .Select(like => new {
        Type = "like",
        CreatedAt = like.CreatedAt
    })
    .Concat(db.Comments
        .Where(comment => comment.UserID == currentUserID)
        .Where(comment => comment.CreatedAt > createdSince)
        .OrderByDescending(comment => comment.CreatedAt)
        .Select(comment => new {
            Type = "comment",
            CreatedAt = comment.CreatedAt
        })
    );
```

Add more Concat statements as needed, as long as they are projecting to the same structure (either anon or an actual class) you can merge them into one list.

If you don't like having one huge statement, and have a class to store items (e.g. `Feed`) then select the first one and do `.ToList()`, then you will have a `List<Feed>` that you can call `.AddRange(linqQueryThatReturnsFeedItems)` for each extra set of items you want to include.

Just sort each list and provide extra filters. Once you have them merged into one, you can then sort the merged list.

Comment: I tried doing something along the lines of: http://pastebin.com/4WRYXntJ but I get a `cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#2>` I'm pretty sure the data matches.

Comment: Easiest solution: create a class, and new it up in your select instead of anon classes, e.g. `Select(comment => new Feed { Title = comment.Title, CreatedAt = comment.DatePublished })` then you will be able to concat without issue.